# A product involving complex numbers

Tags: products

Given $ω^3=1$ but $ω≠1$ how would you prove that, $\displaystyle \prod_{m=1}^{2n} (1-ω^{2^m}+ω^{2^{m+1}})=2^{2n}$  ?

I tried but made no progress tackling this.

Comment: I  presume $\omega\ne1$. I suppose you'd show that $1-\omega^{2^m}+\omega^{2^{m+1}}=2$, but that surely isn't true...

Comment: Edited the question. Is it okay now?

Comment: If you want to get out $4^n$, make the product from $0$ to $2n-1$, or $1$ to $2n$.

Comment: @user588826. I have updated the answer accordingly to you edited question.

Comment: @user588826 If the answer solves your problem, please consider accepting it so that it doesn't come under the unanswered section anymore. You may accept it by clicking on the grey check mark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle \prod_{m=1}^{2n} (1-ω^{2^m}+ω^{2^{m+1}})=(1-ω^{2}+ω^{4})*(1-ω^{4}+ω^{8})*(1-ω^{8}+ω^{16})*.... 2n \ times.$

We know $ω^{3k+p}=ω^{p}$

$=(1+ω-ω^{2})*(1-ω+ω^{2})*(1+ω-ω^{2})*.... 2n \ times.$

$= (1-ω+ω^{2})*(1-ω+ω^{2})*...\ n \ times * (1+ω-ω^{2})*(1+ω-ω^{2})*...  n \ times.$

$=(1-ω+ω^{2})^{n}*(1+ω-ω^{2})^{n}$

$=(1-ω+ω^{2}+(ω-ω))^{n}*(1+ω-ω^{2}+(ω^{2}-ω^{2}))^{n}$

As we know $1+ω+ω^{2}=0$ (Ref - [Cube roots of Unity](http://www.math-only-math.com/the-cube-roots-of-unity.html)) , we get :

$=(-2ω^{2})^{n}*(-2ω)^{n}$

$= (4ω^{3})^{n}=4^{n}=2^{2n}$

Comment: In the question, indexing starts from $m=0$ so there would be $n+1$ terms in the product

Comment: @MayureshL. Edited accordingly with the new(edited) question. Thanks for pointing it out.